# Is it a fault if an item cannot be repaired?

Tags: united-kingdom, consumer-protection, european-union

In the UK (and the rest of the EU), if you buy an item as a consumer, the seller is responsible for the item working for a reasonable amount of time. That time runs out eventually, and then you have to pay for a repair yourself. For example, a computer might be expected to work for two years.

However, even after two years I expect that I can repair the item (at my own expense) to use it for longer. If it turns out that a 26 month old item cannot be repaired anymore, can I successfully claim that this is a fault on its own, that this fault ("cannot be repaired after two years") was present when the item was purchased, and that the reasonable time that a computer can be repaired is significantly longer than two years?

Comment: Trying to claim something was irreparable would require fairly convincing proof that you actually had no options for getting it repaired. With a computer, that's... pretty much impossible. Any local repair shop would happily help you out. Did they actually tell you it was irreparable or simply that *they* couldn't repair it for you?

Answer (score 1):

To say that a computer should last more than two years is perfectly reasonable but unless you are really willing to go through a long lengthy process and really take it to small claims court (It doesn't cost much £50-£100 and you can represent yourself) then it may be easier to fix yourself. Because they can just flat out refuse as it is outside of warranty and leave no other option than the courts. Even though they may be breaching the Consumer Rights Act about being of satisfactory quality.

The Guardian actually has a good article here:
https://www.theguardian.com/money/2006/mar/25/consumernews.howtocomplain

The article is talking about the Sale of Goods act which is no longer relevant. The current Consumer Rights act encompasses pretty much everything from SoG act so the article is still relevant.

Or this one:
https://www.which.co.uk/consumer-rights/advice/what-do-i-do-if-i-have-a-faulty-product

Even though it sucks fixing the computer yourself is always an option it is in no way irreparable. They are fairly simple to put together and replace parts. If you know whats wrong with it, it could be a fairly cheap fix.

Answer (score 0):

The law states that items must last a "reasonable length of time". 2 years is not reasonable for a computer. Typically courts consider six years for items like computers to be reasonable, but it depends on the specific model and circumstances.

In any case, you could likely argue that the item did not last a reasonable length of time and claim a partial refund. The refund is calculated based on how long it lasted vs. how long you would reasonably expect it to, so in your case just over 2 years out of an expected 6 would translate to a 66% refund.

You can present this argument to the retailer. If they refuse, you can use Small Claims Court.